# not able to run react-native project android version

Tags: android, react-native

react-native run-android shows 
env: sh\r: No such file or directory

[image]

Comment: did you try npm install once ?

Comment: yes but getting same error

Comment: is this events and post status type app?

Comment: and please try once to run android portion in android studio

Comment: in the android studio I am getting the error: cannot find symbol variable CLIP_SAVE_FLAG

Comment: do you have node_modules folder in your project root?

Comment: @PratapvarmaPenmetsa please remove that, it will solve your issue

Answer (score 1):

try to clean and rebuild your project

1. react-native start --reset-cache
2. cd android
3. gradlew clean
4. gradlew assembleDebug

or you can simply reinstall **npm modues**

Answer (score 0):

See if you've done this.

1. `npm install -g react-native-cli`
2. `react-native init yourproject`
3. `cd yourproject && react-native run-android`

Comment: its already an existing react-native project cloned from git not able to run android version